# Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need help, unable to start the chromedriver, It is installed, I use webdriver manager.
`path_to_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install() driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path_to_driver), options=driver_options)`

## selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Manual installation did not help

Answer (score 0):

You have provided very little info on what the problem could be. Please add a bit more code to shown what you have done before this. Also what seems to work for me is shown below. Could you try it out

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

ser = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chro_opts = Options()
chro_opts.add_argument("no-sandbox")
chro_opts.....
...
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chro_opts, service=ser)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the driver can't find the `chrome.exe` executable.

Make sure, that you have installed [chrome](https://www.google.de/intl/de/chrome/)